# Search an array of objects in Mongo for any values contained in array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm trying to search Mongo to see if any of the strings in my array are being used in my "images.src.large":

Strings to search for:

```
['/california/los-angeles/pool.jpg','/california/los-angeles/pizza.jpg']
```

Sample of what would be in my Mongo collection:

```
{
    "_id": someNumber,
    "name: "Name 1",
    "images": [
        {
            "title": "Title 1",
            "src": {
                "small": "/california/los-angeles/pool-small.jpg",
                "medium": "/california/los-angeles/pool-medium.jpg",
                "large": "/california/los-angeles/pool.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "title": "Title 2",
            "src": {
                "small": "/california/los-angeles/oven-small.jpg",
                "medium": "/california/los-angeles/oven-medium.jpg",
                "large": "/california/los-angeles/oven.jpg"
            }
        }
    ],
},
{
    "_id": someOtherNumber,
    "name: "Name 2",
    "images": [
        {
            "title": "Landscape",
            "src": {
                "small": "/alaska/badger/dog-small.jpg",
                "medium": "/alaska/badger/dog-medium.jpg",
                "large": "/alaska/badger/dog.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "title": "Food",
            "src": {
                "small": "/alaska/badger/pizza-small.jpg",
                "medium": "/alaska/badger/pizza-medium.jpg",
                "large": "/alaska/badger/pizza.jpg"
            }
        }
    ],
},
{
    "_id": aDifferentNumber,
    "name: "Bridge",
    "images": [
        {
            "title": "Store",
            "src": {
                "small": "/hawaii/kilauea/pool-small.jpg",
                "medium": "/hawaii/kilauea/pool-medium.jpg",
                "large": "/hawaii/kilauea/pool.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "title": "Home",
            "src": {
                "small": "/hawaii/kilauea/tree-small.jpg",
                "medium": "/hawaii/kilauea/tree-medium.jpg",
                "large": "/hawaii/kilauea/tree.jpg"
            }
        }
    ],
},
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is search my collection to see if the image is being used by searching the value of "images.src.large".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the `$in` operator, described in [this page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) in the documentation. You can query a field for any of several values. So the following query in your sample documents would have the result below.

```
> db.images.find({ "images.src.large" :
      { "$in" : ["/california/los-angeles/pool.jpg",
                 "/california/los-angeles/pizza.jpg"]
      }
  }).pretty();

{
    "_id" : 1,
    "name" : "Name 1",
    "images" : [
        {
            "title" : "Title 1",
            "src" : {
                "small" : "/california/los-angeles/pool-small.jpg",
                "medium" : "/california/los-angeles/pool-medium.jpg",
                "large" : "/california/los-angeles/pool.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "title" : "Title 2",
            "src" : {
                "small" : "/california/los-angeles/oven-small.jpg",
                "medium" : "/california/los-angeles/oven-medium.jpg",
                "large" : "/california/los-angeles/oven.jpg"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that because both images are used in the same document, the query only returns one document. If you include a value that is present in another document, the query will return two documents. For example:

```
> db.images.count({ "images.src.large" :
      { "$in" : ["/california/los-angeles/pool.jpg",
                 "/alaska/badger/dog.jpg"]
      }
  });
2
```